# Amazon ECS error running docker image: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/": permission denied

Tags: node.js, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to run a Docker image from Amazon Elastic Container Registry but every time the task tries to start I get the following error message in ECS tasks logs view.

```
container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/": permission denied
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

# Installing libvips-dev for sharp compatibility
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libvips-dev -y

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Install everything
RUN npm install --verbose

# Build the app
RUN npm run build

# Install pm2
RUN npm install pm2 -g

# Expose 1337 port
EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["pm2-runtime", "start", "npm", "--name", "app-backend", "--", "run", "start"]

USER node
```

Listing the things I've tried / updated.

- I changed my `WORKDIR` so it wasn't inside `usr/src/app`. [Ref](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/603#issuecomment-354765372)
- I changed the location of global npm dependencies so they're not in the root directory: [Reference](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/docs/BestPractices.md#global-npm-dependencies)

  ```
  ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
  ENV PATH=$PATH:/home/node/.npm-global/bin
  ```

Note: I can run the Docker image fine locally

Comment: why are you using pm2 inside docker since docker keeps process running even after reboot (using docker-compose.yml), pm2 is useful if you are running app on host machine.

Comment: @bogdanoff great question that I need to find out because I am not sure, I am running a strapi app and following this https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/amazon-aws.html . However thats for EC2. Are you saying I don't need to do this with docker / ecs & fargate?

Comment: yes, you don't need to. and that's docs is using pm2 because they are assuming you are going to run in host machine not docker.  I use [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#restart) option to keep long services running.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it wasn't to do with my Dockerfile, but my terraform `aws_ecs_task_definition`. I had an `entryPoint`.

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ecs-task-definition" {
  family                   = "app-${terraform.workspace}"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  memory                   = "1024"
  cpu                      = "512"
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs-task-execution-role.arn
  container_definitions    = jsonencode([
    {
      "name": "app-container",
      "image": "${aws_ecr_repository.ecr.repository_url}:latest",
      "memory": 1024,
      "cpu": 512,
      "essential": true,
      "entryPoint": ["/"], <!-- This was the culprit.
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 1337,
          "hostPort": 1337
        }
      ],
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "app-log-group-${terraform.workspace}",
          "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
          "awslogs-create-group": "true",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      }
    }])
}
```